# Is argmax working properly for an array of Strings?

Tags: julia, argmax

I'm using the function Argmax to get the string with max size in an array of Strings, and when the string contains a repetition of a single character, the result get weird.

For example:

```
x = ["ABC", "AAAA"]
argmax(x) # 1
# The return of argmax is 1, is that correct ?

x = ["ABC", "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD"]
argmax(x) # = 1

x = ["ABC", "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD", "ABCD"]
argmax(x) # = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are compared lexicographically here, not by their length.

For this reason "ABC" is considered to be greater than "AAAA", and so the maximum element in the array `["ABC", "AAAA"]` is indeed at index 1.

If your goal is to compare the strings by length, you could apply the `length` function to each of the strings in the array and then use `argmax`. For example:

```
julia> x = ["ABC", "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD", "ABCD"]
julia> argmax(length.(x))
2
```